# Custom Google Analytics dimension not showing up on dashboard

Tags: angular, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am using the following code to set my custom google analytic dimension in Angular:

```
var date_enrolled = '11/11/2021 11:59 AM';
gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXX', { 'enrollment_date':  date_enrolled});
```

I am running this on my localhost:4200. When I go to the page localhost:4200/emp then this code gets called. Now in google analytics (from browser) I followed this url:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en&ref_topic=2709827#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

and created a custom dimension. But when I add my custom dimension to one of the insights it does not show any records. Can you please let me know what I might be missing here.

Answer (score 0):

To send a custom dimension to Google Analytics, update the config for your property to set the custom_map parameter for the dimension and then use the custom parameter to send the value of the custom dimension:

```
// Configures custom dimension<Index> to use the custom parameter
// 'dimension_name' for 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', where <Index> is a number
// representing the index of the custom dimension.
gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', {
  'custom_map': {'dimension<Index>': 'dimension_name'}
});

// Sends the custom dimension to Google Analytics.
gtag('event', 'any_event_name', {'dimension_name': dimension_value});
```